# How can I get data in an Oracle CLOB that is greater than 32k into a LONG?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a way to get the CLOB data into a LONG?  It's just a really large XML string.  This is for a legacy system and we unfortunately cannot get away from the LONG at the moment.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm curious if this can be done through PL/SQL because what we have tried involves iterating through the CLOB but then your reach variable size limits.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://psoug.org/reference/long2clob.html

Comment: Divide and store maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can split the XML string into two or more columns? I know you can't move away from LONG, but perhaps you can create a second column and store part of the value (e.g. the header or some of the outside XML tags) and the details in the original column? It would mean that the value is stored in two columns (which isn't ideal) but it could solve your problem?

Not the ideal solution, but it could get you thinking of alternatives.

Comment: XML documents can be 10s or 100s of MB, I've processed XML over 1GB in size. This isn't a solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's not an ideal solution, especially if you have large XML strings like you suggested, but perhaps it works for the OP's needs, or at least causes them to think of an alternative solution.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot insert strings longer than 32k into a long column in PL/SQL.  You can do it with programming languages like Java, C, VB, C# (there are many examples out there).  However, **long** columns were deprecated by Oracle over 20 years ago (for good reasons as they have lots of limitations), you really should have converted to CLOBs by now.  There is no reason whatsoever to have them in your DB - even the old legacy excuse is a moot point - especially as conversion is relatively easy.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_long_lob.htm#i1023103

Comment: As the OP states, converting to CLOB is not an option.  We know they are deprecated and how limited they are.  Is there an answer somewhere in this?

Comment: Why is it not an option? I work on a legacy system (3 million lines of code, system 25 years old) and we converted LONGs to CLOBs.

Comment: Because they changed it and it broke the application.  We don't have access to the code for the application.  So they tried to revert to the backup which also failed... oops.  Now they are trying to change it back to a long.  I work in C# so just used that to convert.  Just trying to help my dba guys.